# How to use CakeDc\Auth with unanthenticated allowed actions?

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, authorization, cakedc

With CakePHP 4.0 and [CakeDc\Auth](https://github.com/CakeDC/auth/tree/6.0.0) 6.0, I tried to setup a RBAC-based permissions app using middleware implementation (instead of Components).

Everything works okay, besides actions which should be accessible without authentication (like `/login`, `/logout`, `/recover`).

Following [Authentication docs](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html#getting-started), I included that actions in my `UsersController::beforeFilter`, but I get exception from: `ROOT/vendor/cakephp/authorization/src/Middleware/RequestAuthorizationMiddleware.php`

```php
$identity = $request->getAttribute($this->getConfig('identityAttribute'));

$result = $service->canResult($identity, $this->getConfig('method'), $request);
    if (!$result->getStatus()) {
        throw new ForbiddenException($result);          <---- That line
    }

    return $handler->handle($request);
}
```

My `Application.php` basic setup is here: https://gist.github.com/CauanCabral/27bdb295f7854116e875e4b0c4471289

What I'm missing?

Comment: That error doesn't stem from authentication, but from authorization, the latter decides whether the authenticated identity is authorized to access a given resource, in this case a request (endpoint). What does your `RequestPolicy` look like?

Comment: You are right about authorization origin, but my only applied Policy came from https://github.com/CakeDC/auth/blob/6.0.0/src/Policy/RbacPolicy.php

Comment: I guess if https://github.com/CakeDC/auth/blob/6.0.0/src/Rbac/Rbac.php#L185 should accept empty($user), as I don't have an user logged?

Comment: I have zero experience with the plugin, but from looking at the code it would seem that the `all bypass` rule in the default permissions would be responsible for allowing access to the default routes: **https://github.com/CakeDC/auth/blob/6.0.0/config/permissions.php#L54-L78**. The `allowed` key seems to be used only in the rule for the `resetOneTimePasswordAuthenticator` action, but as a callable. The `allowed` key evaluation that you've linked seems to _require_ a user, it would only return `true` when `$user` is not empty. So it probably all depends on the permissions that you are using.

Comment: And probably also depends on whether you're using custom routes and/or custom controllers for the `/login`, `/logout`, etc URLs.

Comment: I see, I think the `bypassAuth` is mandatory for actions allowed (as they define in default permissions example). Suspected that, but docs says `ONLY when using Rbac within the RbacMiddleware: Another special key is bypassAuth, if set to true will allow the request, even if there is no user data.` and as I'm not using RbacMiddleware - thought it not applied to me. Thanks.